# How to calculate average weekly spend with groupby, with week being Monday to Sunday?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a customer dataframe with purchase amounts and date. In this case I have two customers, `A` and `B`:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(index=pd.date_range('2015-04-24', periods = 50)).assign(purchase=[x for x in range(51,101)])
df2 = pd.DataFrame(index=pd.date_range('2015-04-28', periods = 50)).assign(purchase=[x for x in range(0,50)])

df3 = pd.concat([df1,df2], keys=['A','B'])

df3 = df3.rename_axis(['user','date']).reset_index()
print(df3.head())

  user       date  purchase
0    A 2015-04-24        51
1    A 2015-04-25        52
2    A 2015-04-26        53
3    A 2015-04-27        54
4    A 2015-04-28        55
```

I would just like to know the user's mean weekly spend, with a week being from Monday to Sunday. Expected outcome:

```
  user       average_weekly_spend 
0    A       51
1    B       60
```

However I can't figure out how to set it as Monday to Sunday. For now I am using `resample` with `7D`. This means all customers would have a different definition of a week, I think. I believe it takes the 7 days from the first purchase and so on. So every customer will have a different starting date.

```
df3.groupby('user').apply(lambda x: x.resample('7D', on='date').mean()).groupby('user')['purchase'].mean()


user
A    78.125
B    27.125
```

Is it possible to define my own week as Monday to Sunday, for all customers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Python, the date range is already indexed Monday to Sunday.

If you just use the pandas.Series.dt.week method to get the week number, this is easy.

```
df3['week_number'] = df3['date'].dt.week
df3.head(20)
```

You can check in the df3 above, week 18 starts on 2015-04-27, which is a Monday.

```
df4 = df3.groupby(['user','week_number']).mean()

# Final mean
df4.groupby(['user']).mean()
```

I think this is the correct average weekly spend. This isn't, however, the same as what you shared in your post as Expected Outcome.

```
Output:

user    purchase
A   74.625
B   26.250
```

Comment: What's interesting is all three answers here have different values.

Comment: @SCool: Can be only one correct answer, though :) I checked the math by hand, after reducing the original dataframe to 30 entries (periods=15), and in my code it adds up. So the other answers cannot be correct. Could you please do a check on your side as well, and pick one answer?

Comment: I'll check it once I get in to work and get back to you

Answer (score 5):

It seems you need `W-Mon` frequency:

```
df = (df3.groupby('user')
         .resample('W-Mon', on='date')['purchase']
         .mean()
         .mean(level=0)
         .reset_index())
print (df)
  user  purchase
0    A      75.5
1    B      28.7
```

Not sure if here is good solution use `mean` of `mean`s, maybe you can get counts and sums with resample and then create means by definition - sums divide by counts:

```
df = (df3.groupby('user')
         .resample('W-Mon', on='date')['purchase']
         .agg(['size','sum'])
         .sum(level=0))
df['mean'] = df.pop('sum') / df.pop('size')
print (df)
      mean
user      
A     75.5
B     24.5
```

Comment: Everybody here has different answers values in their answer!

Comment: @SCool I guess because mean of means.

Answer (score 2):

Another solution with `to_period`, interestingly, gives a different answer:

```
df3.groupby(['user',df3.date.dt.to_period('W-MON')]).mean().mean(level='user')
```

Output:

```
      purchase
user          
A       75.500
B       27.125
```

Comment: All three answers here give different values. Hmm!